# Как сделать такой ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Очень популярный шаблон, как его реализовать?

[image]

Comment: Что именно нужно реализовать из очень популярного: разделение по алфавиту в списке, полосу с алфавитом справа, аватарки в кружках, поиск сверху.. ?

Comment: Мне нужно разделение по алфавиту в списке, но узнать как сделать остальные я тоже бы не отказался =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это называется Indexed `ListView`. Существует полно библиотек, например:

- https://github.com/rizafu/Android-Swipe-StickyHeader-PullToRefresh-Indexable-ListView
- https://github.com/ufo22940268/Android-CityIndexableListView

Строка поиска над списком - это обычный `SearchView`

Comment: https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ListViewVariants Я нашел эти но они достаточно громоздкие

Comment: @Auriwield, зачем это мне?

Comment: Не за чем) Просто если кто придет на этот вопрос, то увидит.

Comment: @Auriwield, в ваших библиотеках нет полосы с индексом справа. не уверен, что она вам нужна, но на картинке она есть